# Dask .loc only the first result (iloc[0])

Tags: pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

Sample dask dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'col_2': list('abcdefg')}, 
                  index=pd.Index([0,0,1,2,3,4,5]))
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

Now I would like to only get first (based on the index) result back - like this in pandas:

```
df.loc[df.col_1 >3].iloc[0]
   col_1 col_2
2      4     d
```

[I know there is no positional row indexing in dask using `iloc`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-indexing.html#positional-indexing), but I wonder if it would be possible to **limit the query to 1 result like in SQL**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - But not sure about the efficiency here:

```
tmp = df.loc[df.col_1 >3] 
tmp.loc[tmp.index == tmp.index.min().compute()].compute()
```